# Inline definition lists

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a definition list to display properly with CSS so that the term and definition are inline, but multiple terms or definitions after one another are displayed as a block element. So

```
<dl>
  <dt>Term</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>
  <dt>Term</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>
  <dt>Term</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>
  <dd>Definition</dd>
</dl>
```

Should display as:

**Term** Definition
**Term** Definition
**Term** Definition
Definition

But for some reason, it doesn't line up right. If I have simple code like the above, it works fine, but if I include any block elements within a `<dd>` it fails and makes everything a block element. I do not want this. I'm using this CSS:

```
dl.inline dt, dl.inline dd {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}

dl.inline dd + dt, dl.inline dd + dd {
    clear: left;
}
```

What am I missing to get it to behave?

Comment: In what browser are you testing this? In chromium 12 and ff4 it looks alright http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/E6qqP/

Comment: Are you aware that `display: inline; float: left` is redundant? If you specify `float: left`, then `display` is automatically set to `block`. The only use for also setting `display: inline` is to fix float margins in *IE6*. Do you care about IE6?

Comment: your havent given your classes to the tags.... <dl class="inline"> thy this....

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/nLGar/1/

```
dl.inline dt, dl.inline dd {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    background: #ccc
}
dl.inline dd + dt, dl.inline dd + dd {
    clear: left
}
dl.inline dd + dd {
    float: none
}
dl.inline dt {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Float elements are automatically displayed as a block elements and display:inline rule is ignored.

```
dl.inline dt, dl.inline dd {
    display: inline;
}
dl.inline dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you want to set margin-right, you have use display: inline-block